# Let $F=\Bbb{F}_3[x]/(f(x))$ and $\alpha=x+f(x) \Bbb{F}_3 \in F$, so that $f(\alpha)=0$ Prove that f(x) is irreducible

Tags: linear-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+1 \in \Bbb{F}_3[x]$. Let $F=\Bbb{F}_3[x]/(f(x))$ and $\alpha=x+f(x) \Bbb{F}_3 \in F$, so that $f(\alpha)=0$ Prove that f(x) is irreducible.

Gauss' lemma: suppose $f \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ is monic of degree>0. Then f is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ if and only if it is irreducible when viewed as an element of $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

Theorem:(reduction mod p). Suppose $f \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ is a monic polynomial of degree >0. Set $f_p \in \Bbb{Z}_{mod p}[x]$ to be the reduction mod p of f. If $f_p \in \Bbb{Z}_{mod p}[x]$ is irreducible for some prime p, then f is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$

Can I directly argue with the second theorem since $f_3$ is irreducible by that theorem?

Comment: Take care about the fact that here $f_3 (x)$ is exactly your $f(x)$ (you can see $f(x)$ arises from a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ after reduction modulo $3$). Recall in $\mathbb{F}_3$ you have just $3$ elements, namely $0,1,2$. Since $f(x)$ has degree $3$, a factorization of it should be $f(x) =(x-a)g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a degree-2 polynomial. That factorization holds if at least one of the $0,1,2$ is a root of $f(x)$. Then compute $f(a)$ for $a=0,1,2$ and you will see that it is always different from zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ has degree $3$, $f$ is reducible in $\Bbb F_3[x]$ if and only if $f$ has a root in $\Bbb F_3$.
A direct computation shows that any of $0,1,2\in\Bbb F_3$ is a root of $f$, hence $f$ is irreducible in $\Bbb F_3[x]$.